# How to display keyboard by code when open app on UWP App installed on surface tablet?

Tags: uwp, windows-10, tablet

I need to display the keyboard by code when i open the UWP App installed on microsoft surface. I have searched a lot in internet but i can't find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display the touch screen keyboard, simply add the following.

`InputPane.GetForCurrentView().TryShow();`

**EDIT**

You may also be able to display the touch screen keyboard without an input field selected by using [FullTrustProcessLauncher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher) to open OSK.exe (On Screen Keyboard) whenever you like. This could give you some issues when publishing to the store (I can't confirm that 100%), but if you are sideloading anyway then this would probably be your best option.

Comment: This only works after button clicked or some interaction with the app, i would like to show the keyboard when the app opens without having an event. Thanks

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you can run osk.exe in UWP using FullTrustProcessLauncher which will open your on-screen keyboard. However, you will likely have problems when submitting your application to the app store. If you are sideloading then this may be a solution for you. Added a link above.

Comment: Finally i called InputPane.GetForCurrentView().TryShow() inside WindowVisibilityChangedEventHandler() that executes on the app prelaunch and this worked to me. Thanks!

Comment: Good solution, glad you were able to find a workaround.